# How do I transfer a Azure Function script to Visual Studio?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

If I create an Azure Function in the Azure portal, how do I grab the script and edit it in Visual Studio? I know I can copy the C# code from the script window but that's only part of the Function. How do I grab everything - the code, triggers, outputs, etc. - and take that into Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1):

There's a button right in the Function App blade in Azure that allows you to download the contents of the function app: [image]

You can even choose to download the Content and the Visual Studio project so you can directly import it into VS. However, as Travis mentioned you should really be doing this the other way around and keeping your development in VS and then using one of the various deployment options to push your functions to Azure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use FTP or Kudu(.scm.azurewebsites.net) to download the app contents.

Generally speaking though if you want to work in Visual Studio it's better to do your work there and then deploy to the app with one of the several deployment options.

Answer (score 0):

Once your migrate the files (as noted in the other answers), you'll also note that Visual Studio encourages a different programming model than the portal:

- Precompile *.cs instead of .csx
- Instead of Function.json, you use the attributes (ala WebJobs SDK).

So to fully work in VS and leverage the VS build system (and unit tests, and other VS features), you'll need to migrate your code. 
See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/05/10/azure-function-tools-for-visual-studio-2017/ for more detail on webjobs.